# Read JSON key : value pair

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I read the whole JSON file but I need to read values from key rating and store into ArrayList,here is code but it does not do anything

```
        ArrayList<Object> rates = new ArrayList<>();

        FileReader read = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\Task\\files\\reviews.json");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(read);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray reviews = new JSONArray();
        reviews = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");

        Iterator<Entry> itr1 = reviews.iterator();
        while (itr1.hasNext()) {

            Map rate= ((Map)jsonObject.get("rating"));
            Iterator<Entry> itr2 = ((JSONObject) itr1.next()).entrySet().iterator();
            while (itr2.hasNext()) {
                if(itr2.equals("rating")) {
                rates.add(itr2);
                Map.Entry pair = itr2.next();
                System.out.println(rate);
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: what's the structure of your json data?

Comment: Here is JSON:```{
"reviews":
[
  {
    "id": 2097047,
    "reviewId": "93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f",
    "reviewFullText": "5 star review",
    "reviewText": "5 star review",
    "numLikes": 0,
    "numComments": 0,
    "numShares": 0,
    "rating": 5,
    "reviewCreatedOn": "2 months ago",

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;` what is the point of creating `new JSONObject();` if you immediately discard it by reassigning `jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;`? Instead simply write `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;`. Same with `JSONArray reviews = new JSONArray(); reviews = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");`, simply write `JSONArray reviews = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");`.

Comment: Anyway `Map rate= ((Map)jsonObject.get("rating"));` doesn't look right. What do you think should happen here (note what `jsonObject` holds)?

Comment: Yes, Map is not right, I want to go to "rating" key, how can I do it? Should I create JSONObject?

Comment: Please include the imports in your sample code for better understanding about the library/libraries you're using. Thanks!

Comment: import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Rate {

Comment: I can not include in the code above, it is very long

Comment: You can try this way `List<String> ratings = (List<String>) reviews.stream()
                .map(o -> ((JSONObject) o).get("rating").toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`. Note that you don't need nested `while` with additional iteration since you just need to iterate over JSONObjects from `JSONArray reviews` which you are doing via `Iterator<Entry> itr1` (which should be `Iterator itr1` or `Iterator<?> itr1`). Using `itr1.next()` returns `JSONObjects`. You just need to cast it to `JSONObjects` to be able to call `get("rating")` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Based from what you've provided so far, perhaps this code snippet will give you some idea:

```java
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

// This will be what you have in your JSON file.
String content = "{\n" +
        "  \"reviews\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\": 2097047,\n" +
        "      \"reviewId\": \"93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f\",\n" +
        "      \"reviewFullText\": \"5 star review\",\n" +
        "      \"reviewText\": \"5 star review\",\n" +
        "      \"numLikes\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"numComments\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"numShares\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"rating\": 5,\n" +
        "      \"reviewCreatedOn\": \"2 months ago\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\": 2097048,\n" +
        "      \"reviewId\": \"123131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f\",\n" +
        "      \"reviewFullText\": \"4 star review\",\n" +
        "      \"reviewText\": \"4 star review\",\n" +
        "      \"numLikes\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"numComments\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"numShares\": 0,\n" +
        "      \"rating\": 4,\n" +
        "      \"reviewCreatedOn\": \"3 months ago\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        "}";

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
List<Integer> rates = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(content);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");
    
    for (Iterator<JSONObject> itr = jsonArray.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        JSONObject item = itr.next();

        // do your stuff here for rating. I simply added it in the list right here.
        rates.add(((Long) item.get("rating")).intValue());
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your prompt and your example code, this code snippet can help you

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestQ68867649 {

    @Test
    void testQ68867649() throws IOException, ParseException {
        ArrayList<Long> rates = new ArrayList();

        FileReader read = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\Task\\files\\reviews.json");
        
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(read);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray reviews = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");

        for (Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = reviews.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            JSONObject rate = iterator.next();
            rates.add((Long) rate.get("rating"));
        }

        System.out.println("rates values: " + rates);
    }
}
```

***reviews.json file example data based on the data provided by you***

```
{
  "reviews": [
    {
      "id": 2097047,
      "reviewId": "93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f",
      "reviewFullText": "5 star review",
      "reviewText": "5 star review",
      "numLikes": 0,
      "numComments": 0,
      "numShares": 0,
      "rating": 5,
      "reviewCreatedOn": "2 months ago"
    },
    {
      "id": 2097047,
      "reviewId": "93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f",
      "reviewFullText": "5 star review",
      "reviewText": "5 star review",
      "numLikes": 0,
      "numComments": 0,
      "numShares": 0,
      "rating": 3,
      "reviewCreatedOn": "2 months ago"
    }
  ]
}
```

***Output base on the data used as example***
`rates values: [5, 3]`

***pom.xml file***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>q68867649</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**NOTE:** this example was developed using Java 8 and Maven